# vuejs: how to pass the value to data as Array?

Tags: arrays, vue.js, push

I'm passing the value of object as props into my "data" `studentId` inside the form

```
data() {
    return {
      form: new Form({
        studentId: []
      })
    };
  },
```

In my `method`, the classlists has initial value, which are the id  of students

```
insertScore() {
      let students = this.classlists;   //<---this is my props
      let element = [];
      let s = [];
      for (let index = 0; index < students.length; index++) {
        element = students[index].id; 
      }
    }

        //id: 7
        //id:29
        //id:30
```

What i need is to make my `classlists ids` to be an array and store it into my `studentId` like `studentId = [7,29,30]` , but what i'm getting when i console.log is separate Ids

Props:
[image: my props]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what are you trying to achieve but if you want new array with only specific property from the `classlist`, this should do work.

```
insertScore() {
    const elements = this.classlists.map(e=>e.id)
}
```

Comment: yes,this did the work.  the `elements` return as an array, but I also need this to pass into my `studentId`.

Comment: `const elements = this.classlists.map(e => (this.form.studentId = e.id));` i tried this but what i get is only the last value

Comment: just add a line at the bottom `this.form.studentId = elements` inside `insertScore`

Comment: oh i alerady get the studentId `const elements = this.classlists.map(e => e.id);
      this.form.studentId = elements;`. Thank you for your help